# Is there a difference between the `if else` and the `if-else if-else`?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, assembly, compilation

In [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) article for `Binary Search` there is a section called `Deferred detection of equality` which presents a somewhat "optimized" version of binary search as follows:

```
int binary_search(int A[], int key, int imin, int imax)  
{  
  while (imax > imin)  
  {  
    int imid = (imin + imax) / 2;  
    if (A[imid] < key)  
      imin = imid + 1;  
    else  
      imax = imid;  
  }  
  if((imax == imin) && (A[imin] == key))  
    return imin;  
  else  
    return KEY_NOT_FOUND;  
}
```

It is claimed that this is a better version than the conventional textbook binary search since the `.... algorithm uses only one conditional branch per iteration`
Is this true? I mean the `if` instructions are translated in `CMP` and `Branch` instructions in assembly so I can not think how an `if-else` is better than an `if-else if-else`
Is there such a difference that I should take into account in higher level languages? The code of the "deffered" version seems more tight I admin, but are there optimizations or penalties in how you form `if-else` statements?

Comment: I would guess that your source is talking about assembly and not Java in which case I would think that it would not apply.  Also, I bet that it is not taking into account modern day code optimization.

Comment: Also, I hope that this is an academic question because if you are making programming decisions based on this sort of performance evaluations then it is the definition of premature optimization.

Comment: You're not showing the other alternative, so it's impossible to know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Gray:No textbook,wikipedia. And this is not a programming decision.Just some recap in my spare hours back to basics

Comment: And there is no "textbook" version of binary search -- it can be coded a thousand different ways.

Comment: @HotLicks:The other alternative is the well known `if(a[mid] == key){}else if (a[mid] < key) else{}`

Comment: You'd have to analyze it statistically to see which was faster, since the "faster" version is apt to iterate several more times, on average.

Comment: Just flipping around the if statements, then, should have the same effect, right?

Comment: Well in practice the `if/else` is pretty unpredictable, as is the `if/else if` so there's no advantage there. The `else if/else` part on the other hand *is* pretty easy to predict (take the else if), so in practice that solution won't save much and means we don't stop early. You'll have to benchmark the solutions, but on a modern CPU I don't think the difference will be noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key concept is that it uses one less conditional *per iteration*. That is, the equality check has been moved outside the `while` loop so that it only runs once, while in the basic version it would need to be checked every time¹.

That said, I 'm not sure if there would actually be a measurable difference when using the optimized form. For example, consider that:

1. If all you are comparing is two integers then the compiler can detect that it can compute the comparison result just once and then evaluate which branch to take just as well.
2. Binary search is O(logN), so the number of iterations taken would actually be very small even if the number of elements to search is quite large. It's arguable whether you 'd *see* any difference.
3. The implementation of modern CPUs features such as speculative execution and branch prediction (especially in "nice" algorithms like binary search) might very well have more visible effects than this optimization (out of my league to check though).

**Notes:**

¹ Actually it is *another* condition that doesn't need to be checked when the equality comparison moves out, but conceptually there is no difference.

Comment: +1.This makes sense.But the article the way it is phrased seems to imply something different (at least in how I understand it)

Comment: In the referenced Wikipedia article, there's a version right above the one described by the OP that does if(>)elseif(<)else(=).  The equality returns the value, so when it's not equal, it doesn't even get there, I don't see how that version is any different.

Comment: A comparison is one of the cheapest instructions on modern CPUs, the expensive part are branch mispredictions. So if the second version doesn't help to save on those the number of cycles saved is negligible.

Comment: @spinning_plate: Theoretically it needs to always calculate `elseif(<)` every time though. That's what my note #1 says.

Comment: @Voo: I agree with that, but it might be the case that we are not talking about integers so the comparison could be arbitrarily costly.

Comment: @Jon True enough. In that case we'd have rewrite it to call compareTo only once if performance was important and then we'd be back to the standard case. Ignoring that possibility and assuming integers, in practice the second branch should be highly predictable so should cost about a cycle. Also with expensive compareTos stopping earlier should amortize the additional costs quickly - that gets a bit involved though.

Comment: @jon -- On many processors the compare for `=` and `<` will be done in a single operation, for ints and floats.  The only added cost is the test of the condition code in the branch instruction (and a few processors have 3-way branches to bury that cost).